# Roles php mysql

Tags: php, users-roles, cuenta-usuario

ayuda necesito hacerr un login con roles mejor dicho ya hice el login pero no se como ni donde implementar la validacion del rol por favor ayuda adjunto el codigo del login

```
    <?php

   /**
 * Class login
      * handles the user's login and logout process
 */
   class Login
{
/**
 * @var object The database connection
 */
private $db_connection = null;
/**
 * @var array Collection of error messages
 */
public $errors = array();
/**
 * @var array Collection of success / neutral messages
 */
public $messages = array();

/**
 * the function "__construct()" automatically starts whenever an object of this class is created,
 * you know, when you do "$login = new Login();"
 */
public function __construct()
{
    // create/read session, absolutely necessary
    session_start();

    // check the possible login actions:
    // if user tried to log out (happen when user clicks logout button)
    if (isset($_GET["logout"])) {
        $this->doLogout();
    }
    // login via post data (if user just submitted a login form)
    elseif (isset($_POST["login"])) {
        $this->dologinWithPostData();
    }
}

/**
 * log in with post data
 */
private function dologinWithPostData()
{
    // check login form contents
    if (empty($_POST['user_name'])) {
        $this->errors[] = "Username field was empty.";
    } elseif (empty($_POST['user_password'])) {
        $this->errors[] = "Password field was empty.";
    } elseif (!empty($_POST['user_name']) && !empty($_POST['user_password'])) {

        // create a database connection, using the constants from config/db.php (which we loaded in index.php)
        $this->db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

        // change character set to utf8 and check it
        if (!$this->db_connection->set_charset("utf8")) {
            $this->errors[] = $this->db_connection->error;
        }

        // if no connection errors (= working database connection)
        if (!$this->db_connection->connect_errno) {

            // escape the POST stuff
            $user_name = $this->db_connection->real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']);

            // database query, getting all the info of the selected user (allows login via email address in the
            // username field)
            $sql = "SELECT user_id, user_name, firstname, user_email, user_password_hash, user_permision
                    FROM users
                    WHERE user_name = '" . $user_name . "' OR user_email = '" . $user_name . "';";
            $result_of_login_check = $this->db_connection->query($sql);

            // if this user exists
            if ($result_of_login_check->num_rows == 1) {

                // get result row (as an object)
                $result_row = $result_of_login_check->fetch_object();

                // using PHP 5.5's password_verify() function to check if the provided password fits
                // the hash of that user's password
                if (password_verify($_POST['user_password'], $result_row->user_password_hash)) {

                    // write user data into PHP SESSION (a file on your server)
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $result_row->user_id;
                    $_SESSION['firstname'] = $result_row->firstname;
                    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $result_row->user_name;
                    $_SESSION['user_email'] = $result_row->user_email;
                    $_SESSION['user_permision'] = $result_row->user_permision;
                    $_SESSION['user_login_status'] = 1;

                } else {
                    $this->errors[] = "Usuario y/o contraseña no coinciden.";
                }
            } else {
                $this->errors[] = "Usuario y/o contraseña no coinciden.";
            }
        } else {
            $this->errors[] = "Problema de conexión de base de datos.";
        }
    }

}


/**
 * perform the logout
 */
public function doLogout()
{
    // delete the session of the user
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();
    // return a little feeedback message
    $this->messages[] = "Has sido desconectado.";

}

/**
 * simply return the current state of the user's login
 * @return boolean user's login status
 */
public function isUserLoggedIn()
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_login_status']) AND $_SESSION['user_login_status'] == 1) {
        return true;
    }
    // default return
    return false;

}
}


 }
```

Comment: Para hacer eso tienes que modificar la base de datos, me refiero a agregar una tabla de roles(admin, vendedor, usernormal) alli defines eso, luego en php haces una consulta que traiga esos datos, y despues con PHP tendras que usar el **header ("Location:ADMIN.php");** o tienes que redireccionarlo al **header ("Location:NORMAL.php");** algo asi, PD: No quites los creditos a Obed Alvarado "ya hice el login"

Comment: aver no le esoy quitando creditos a nadie solo lo dije como para hacerme entender

Comment: y no lo podria hacer con un switch o un if

Comment: checa [esto](http://www.formacionwebonline.com/crear-sesiones-php-en-intranet/)